# Why does the second for loop only iterate once?

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
with open("t1.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    with open("t2.csv", "rb") as e:
         reader2 = csv.reader(e)
         with open("alnew.csv", "wb") as cr:
             writer = csv.writer(cr)
             for row in reader:
                 print row + ["XXXXX"]
                 for row2 in reader2:
                      print row2 + ["OOOOO"]
                      if row[0] == row2[3]:
                          new = row + row2
                          writer.writerow(new)
```

Shouldn't the second for loop iterate each time it goes through the first loop? It only seems to run the first time it goes through the loop.

Comment: What is the output of of the first `print`?

Comment: You can group file contexts in the same 'with' line, this should help clean up your code. I'm having a hard time seeing what file belongs where.

'with open('t1' ,'w') as one, open('t2','w') as two:'

Comment: `reader2` is exhausted after the first time through. If you want to iterate over it multiple times, you should read it into a list or something

Comment: Do you want to read the lines of `t1.csv` and `t2.csv` in lock-step? (Thus reading each line of each file exactly once.)  Or do you want to read all of the lines of `t2.csv` for each line of `t1.csv`?  (Thus reading each line of `t1.csv` once, and each line of `t2.csv` many times.)

Comment: I want to read all the lines of `t2.csv` for each line of `t1.csv`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you open a file handle to your second file only once.  the second time through the loop it is already exhausted.  File handles like other generators can only be iterated over once without recreating them.  You could reopen the file each time.  However I would prefer `itertools.product` in this case.

```
import csv, itertools
with open("t1.csv", "rb") as f, with open("t2.csv", "rb") as e, with open("alnew.csv", "wb") as cr:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader2 = csv.reader(e)
    writer = csv.writer(cr)
    for row, row2 in itertools.product(reader, reader2)
        if row[0] == row2[3]:
            writer.writerow(row + row2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to "reset" the reader. As it's written, reader2 will get to the end of the file, but doesn't know that it's supposed to go back to the top.

To re-read a file, you can re-open the file and start over every time.

```
import csv
with open("t1.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    with open("alnew.csv", "wb") as cr:
        writer = csv.writer(cr)
        for row in reader:
            print row + ["XXXXX"]
            with open("t2.csv", "rb") as e:
                reader2 = csv.reader(e)
                for row2 in reader2:
                     print row2 + ["OOOOO"]
                     if row[0] == row2[3]:
                         new = row + row2
                         writer.writerow(new)
```

Comment: I don't think `csv.reader` exposes a `seek` method, does it?  It's not documented.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have read `t2.csv` all the way through once, the reader (and the underlying file) remain "at the end" of the file.  They won't reset to the beginning just because you tried to iterate over them again.

For a regular file you could use the `seek` method to deal with this, but (unless I'm missing something) `csv.reader` doesn't have a `seek` method, and probably won't be happy with you if you call `seek` on the underlying file.  So the simplest fix is to read the entire of `t2.csv` into an array: change

```
     reader2 = csv.reader(e)
```

to

```
     reader2 = [row for row in csv.reader(e)]
```

If `t2.csv` is too large for this to be practical, I think you have to *both* call `seek(0)` on the file, and destroy and recreate `reader2`, every time through the outer loop.